# ERC20 Payment processing

Tags: blockchain, solidity

What's wrong with my smart contract, because I get "Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit". On frontend I am calling approveTokens() first and acceptPayment() later

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';

contract PaymentProcessor {
   address public owner;
   IERC20 public token;

constructor(address _owner, address _token) {
    owner = _owner;
    token = IERC20(_token);
}

event PaymentCompleted(
    address payer,
    uint256 amount,
    uint paymentId,
    uint timestamp
);

function approveTokens(uint256 amount) public returns(bool){
   token.approve(owner, amount);
   return true;
}

function getAllowance() public view returns(uint256){
    return token.allowance(msg.sender, owner);
}

function acceptPayment(uint256 amount, uint paymentId) payable public {
    require(amount > getAllowance(), "Please approve tokens before transferring");
    token.transfer(owner, amount);

    emit PaymentCompleted(msg.sender, amount, paymentId, block.timestamp);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users need to call `approve()` directly on the `token` address - not through your contract.

Your current implementation approves `owner` to spend `PaymentProcessor`'s tokens because `PaymentProcessor` is the `msg.sender` in the context of the `token` contract.

Comment: Do I have to implement token smart contract? I want to use Polygon Matic token

Comment: @krakas On your frontend app, you just need to build (and broadcast) a transaction invoking the `approve()` function on the `token` address instead of your current approach invoking `approveTokens()` on the `PaymentCompleted` address.